# Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool PHP 7.4.7

Tags: php, web

Soy nuevo en el mundo de desarrollo web y estoy realizando un sistema de punto de venta, hasta ahora todo ha estado bastante bien. El problema surgió que al parecer debido a la ultima actualización de PHP, me está tirando el siguiente error:

**Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\stydpos\vistas\modulos\ventas.php on line 121**.

El código es el siguiente:

```
$itemUsuario = "id";
                  $valorUsuario = $value["id_vendedor"];
                  $respuestaUsuario = ControladorUsuarios::ctrMostrarUsuarios($itemUsuario, $valorUsuario);

              echo '

              <td>'.$respuestaUsuario["nombre"].'</td>
              <td>'.$value["metodo_pago"].'</td>
              <td>$ '.number_format($value["neto"],0).'</td>
              <td>$ '.number_format($value["total"],0).'</td>
              <td>'.$value["fecha"].'</td>

              <td>
```

**Gracias por su ayuda.**

Comment: Cual de esas lineas es la 121?

Comment: El error es claro, la base de datos te está devolviendo `false` o un valor interpretado como tal, como 0 resultados: `NULL`. Puedes hacer un un `echo $query;` copias lo que sale y córrelo directo en la base de datos para ver y/o corregir el error. Si el caso es por 0 resultados, entonces tendrás que (1) usar valores default para los campos o (2) usar `while($row=$result...)` para que no entre en ese bucle en caso de no haber registros.

Comment: la linea que me esta dando problema, la 121, es la siguiente <td>'.$respuestaUsuario["nombre"].'</td>

Comment: Haz un `var_dump($respuestaUsuario);` para depurar /  examinar el elemento que te está dando problemas.

Comment: TODO ESTA BIEN, SOLO TIENES q verificar que en tu base de datos todos los ingresos esten completos. Te sale el error porq uno esta incompleto o erroneo.